# Wrong key behavior - french keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and a French keyboard which used to work perfectly. But 3 days ago, the <kbd>l</kbd> key suddenly change to <kbd>!</kbd> on my keyboard. The <kbd>!</kbd> key continue to work correctly however.

I reinstalled Ubuntu but this does not fix the issue. Can you help me? I am quite new to Ubuntu, so I don't really know what do you need to help me, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyony looking after that, it seems that this problem was fixed with Ubuntu update...

Waiting for this update, I used to use this script for each startup :

```
#!/bin/sh
xmodmap -e "keycode 61 = l"
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = exclam"
```

Which aimed to remap my keyboard in most favorable way, be of course not solved the problem.